# how jni system.loadlibrary interact with the global variab in C file

Tags: java-native-interface, global-variables

If i have a global variable int A=0 in the C file. And I have the function in C:

```
int a()
{
  A++;
  return A;
}
```

if I call a() once in the Java application, I will have a return A=1. And if I call a() again, I will have a return of A=2; So I guess the global variable is fixed into a memory when the native library is loaded into the java application?  Please let me know if my guess is correct or not. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I think every native library is only loaded once, just like in any non-Java program, and needed memory (like for global variables) is allocated at that time.

Comment: @RobI So the variable A now performs as a static member in the Class which loads the library? In another word, A will be shared between different instances of that class?

Comment: The `A` variable is global, so it's shared between all instances of the class, and in fact of all classes, within a single process.